# 2012R2 File Server - randomly unable to browse disk

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, filesystems

This is a (new) 2012R2 VM running on a 2012R2 Hyper-V Cluster with DAS Shared Storage for the CSVs.

The is where is gets strange - the server will be working fine without an issue, we will then get reports certain shares are no longer working. I will login to the server, browse to the DATA disk in Explorer, and it will load say the first 10 folders on the drive. This is where the "Green bar of death" kicks in and Explorer sits there unable to load the rest of the drive.

All the folders I can see, the corresponding shares work, but anything that explorer can't load, users cannot access via their mapped drives any longer.

A reboot fixes its all be it only temporarily.

Nothing in the event logs, no performance issues, the VHD itself is fine if I take it outside the VM and mount it on the host.

Looking for any ideas at this stage!

Answer (score 0):

Is there any RAID configured and in use? If so, did you check logs from RAID controller? Sounds like this could be hardware related.